# How to properly send and insert a field data to a column of Time and Date data type

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL for my tests and I've set one column `start_dte` as Date data type while `scheduled_time` and `sla_time` are both Time data type. I've created a form that would allow me to insert new record.

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td>RID:</td> <td><input type="text" name="newrid" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Day:</td> <td><input type="text" name="newday" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Scheduled Time:</td> <td><input type="text" name="newsched" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SLA Time:</td> <td><input type="text" name="newsla" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Start Date:</td> <td><input type="text" name="newsd" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Save" NAME="submit"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The PHP Code right below it is this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $rid = $_POST['newrid'];
        $day = $_POST['newday'];
        $scheduled_time = $_POST['newsched'];
        $sla_time = $_POST['newsla'];
        $start_dte = $_POST['newsd'];
        $data = $dbh->prepare("INSERT into meta_auto_reports.frequency values ($rid, '$day', $scheduled_time, $sla_time, $start_dte)"); 
        $data->execute();
        echo "<h2>Inserted Successfully</h2>";
        $data = null;
    }
?>
```

This shows an error upon submit:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch:

So I'm wondering what's the proper way of formatting user input in a way that postgresql would accept. The Columns are Nullable as well, which means an empty field left blank by a user would have to place `NULL` upon insertion.

Comment: ... and the rest of the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Few comments about this code:

Form values should be stored in an array:

```
<td>RID:</td> <td><input type="text" name="form[newrid]" value=""></td>
<td>Day:</td> <td><input type="text" name="form[newday]" value=""></td>
```

This way, it is easier to manipulate them:

```
$form_data = $_POST['form'];
```

I would strongly suggest you use a library to **validate and clean** the data submitted by end users (symfony/validator does this job but there are many other libraries).

Now, the database part. **Data sent to the database need to be escaped** to protect you application against SQL injection. Using a prepared statement is a way to pass data as parameters:

```
$stmt->prepare("INSERT into meta_auto_reports.frequency values (:id, :day, :scheduled_time …)");
$stmt->execute($form);
```

Using PDO directly does mix different concerns in the same layer of code (the how and the what). Using a library to handle database connectivity and queries is a good idea. (Pomm if specifically using Postgres or any DBAL or ORM if you want database abstraction).